# Limit the amount of records in a spark context

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I would like to reduce the number of records for each reducer, and keep the resulting variable a `rdd`

Using `takeSample` seemed like the obvious choice, however, it returns a `collection` and not a `SparkContext` object.

I came up with this method:

```py
rdd = rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x:x[1]<limit).map(lambda x:x[0])
```

However, this method is very slow and not efficient.

Is there a smarter way to take a small sample and keep the data structure an `rdd` ?

Comment: If the sample can be randomly taken then you can use [randomSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=random#pyspark.RDD.randomSplit) or [sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=random#pyspark.RDD.sample)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It you want a **small** example subset and cannot make any additional assumptions about the data then `take` combined with `parallelize` can be an optimal solution:

```
sc.parallelize(rdd.take(n))
```

It will touch a relatively low number of partitions (only one in the best case scenario) and the cost of network traffic for small *n* should be negligible.

Sampling (`randomSplit` or `sample`) will require a full data scan same as `zipWithIndex` with `filter`.

Assuming there is no data skew you can try something like this to address that:

```
from __future__ import division  # Python 2 only

def limitApprox(rdd, n, timeout):
    count = rdd.countApprox(timeout)
    if count <= n:
        return rdd
    else:
        rec_per_part = count // rdd.getNumPartitions()
        required_parts = n / rec_per_part if rec_per_part else 1
        return rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
            lambda i, iter: iter if i < required_parts else []
        )
```

- this will still access every partition but will try to avoid computing content if not necessary
- won't work if there is large data skew

  - can take much more than required if distribution is uniform but n << than an average number of records per partition.
  - may undersample if distribution is skewed towards high indices.

If data is representable as a `Row` you can try another trick:

```
rdd.toDF().limit(n).rdd
```